# ReactJS + Flux + PHP Sample?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm looking for an example that uses ReactJS+PHP (client-server side) which make uses at the same time of the architecture FLUX?

Any recommendation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flux architecture can work with PHP without any problem, since all the flux architecture is implemented in the javascript at client side. And all the communication with the server can build in simple jsons.

So basically you can look for any flux example with Node.js & just implement all the data call in PHP.

The only problem with the PHP server approach is that you won't be able to implement server-side react rendering in PHP server. And if you interesting in this feature you should build your server in Node.js.

Comment: isn't possible to render on the server side using V8 library on PHP?

Comment: My mistake you right, I found this project for that https://github.com/reactjs/react-php-v8js